# CD driver won't work properly after formatting

Tags: cd-drive

I've formatted my desktop PC, the CDROM drive was working fine. After formatting, it became slow, unresponsive and sometimes it shows error: unable to execute task, error in the I/O device. I've tried reinsalling the driver, but it didn't work. I'd appreciate some ideas. I have a very old PC with winXP on it

Comment: I have to assume that the incidents are unrelated, and its more likely that the CDROM is simply hitting end of life. optical disks, like all spinning media, and slowly, inexorably dying every second they are doing something useful, and opticals are often not engineered to deal with the high tolerances internal hard disks are. I'd recommend replacing it with a DVDRom from any retailer. in the US, you can usually find them for under 20 dollars.

Comment: Also possible it has dropped into PIO mode for some reason. Might be worth checking the steps [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/stuck-in-pio-mode/1189ac64-5828-48b6-b6d4-797cd3e9561c).

Comment: @Frank Thomas I've followed the steps in the link, nothing has worked. So it looks like the drive needs to be replaced

Comment: have you tried cleaning the drive (laser)? There are products specifically for this.